# First bash script help (how to enter usernames passwords)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to make a bash script to log in to my VPN service, using the terminal, openvpn and some config files.

-this is my first ever bash and im reading Linux basics book atm learning terminal commands, im okay but still a noob. going to use nano as my text editor- dont assume 'i know' i am a noob at linux terminal and bash scripts.

```
#change to directory with config files

cd vpn 

#run command that will startup openvpn/ipvanish(config files stored by me)

sudo openvpn --config ipvanish-SG-Singapore-sin-a01.ovpn

#enter sudo password after prompt
"i don't know what to put here"

#enter ipvanish account username
"i don't know what to put here

#enter the password 
"i don't know what to put here"
```

I'm stuck at the points where 'i don't know what to put here' if anyone could help i would really appreciate it. I want to learn so please offer explanations of why

Comment: You can try to use `Expect Script` for that. I made something similar for SSH'ing into servers: https://github.com/NLDev/SSH-Starter

Comment: Please show a typical session of how the program script would look in action.  That is, assume the script was completed and worked perfectly -- show us what the user would see at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your password in a script to sudo with the -S (read password from standard input) option, like this:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

I assume you want to hardcode your sudo password in the script for a cronjob or similar, you should consider executing the script as root

With openvpn you should be able to save your password and username in a file, say `password.txt`, writing them in the first two lines:

```
username
password
```

Then, in your .ovpn file add `auth-user-pass password.txt`. 
See [here](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=11342)